# 12.04 only boots from restart or live USB restart - Desperate

Tags: boot, live-usb

I can only boot into Ubuntu by first booting from my live USB and changing the boot drive in grub. I.e., not from a hard disk installation. After booting re-booting by changing disk priority in BIOS is flawless.

Throughout the history of this problem I get a variety of errors: `Out of disk`, 'Unknown filesystem' (my current error). I've tried fixing it by re-installing GRUB, by using `boot-repair` to re-install GRUB, and several other methods, with no results. Thank god you don't need to shut Ubuntu down frequently.

Under are the results of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c76a2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1        42457088  1943748607   950645760   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1943805952  1953523711     4858880    5  Extended
/dev/sda4   *        2048    42457087    21227520   83  Linux
/dev/sda5      1943808000  1953523711     4857856   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006738d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   312580095   156289024   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 319.4 GB, 319370035200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38827 cylinders, total 623769600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x38040c41

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               2   623769599   311884799    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sde: 32.0 GB, 32016171008 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62531584 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1              32    62531583    31265776    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ ^C
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
255: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
No command 'Units' found, did you mean:
 Command 'units' from package 'units' (universe)
Units: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk identifier: 0x000c76a2
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
Device: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sda1        42457088  1943748607   950645760   83  Linux
bash: /dev/sda1: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sda2      1943805952  1953523711     4858880    5  Extended
bash: /dev/sda2: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sda4   *        2048    42457087    21227520   83  Linux
bash: /dev/sda4: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sda5      1943808000  1953523711     4857856   82  Linux swap / Solaris
bash: /dev/sda5: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Partition table entries are not in disk order
Partition: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
255: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
No command 'Units' found, did you mean:
 Command 'units' from package 'units' (universe)
Units: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk identifier: 0x0006738d
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
Device: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sdb1            2048   312580095   156289024   83  Linux
bash: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk /dev/sdc: 319.4 GB, 319370035200 bytes
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38827 cylinders, total 623769600 sectors
255: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
No command 'Units' found, did you mean:
 Command 'units' from package 'units' (universe)
Units: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk identifier: 0x38040c41
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
Device: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sdc1               2   623769599   311884799    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
bash: /dev/sdc1: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk /dev/sde: 32.0 GB, 32016171008 bytes
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62531584 sectors
255: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
No command 'Units' found, did you mean:
 Command 'units' from package 'units' (universe)
Units: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18
No command 'Disk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
Disk: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ 
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
Device: command not found
jesse@jesse-P35-DS3R:~$ /dev/sde1              32    62531583    31265776    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a link to the Boot-Repair result log in your question. Otherwise no-one will be able to assess your situation.

Comment: Do you mean "out of free disk space"? Maybe you can delete some old kernel images from /boot...

Comment: @Jesse Run `boot-repair` like this

Comment: @DavidFoerster his is the log: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13224497/

Comment: @JesseHuisken, Launch *Disks*, Select your HDD,  Ctrl+S for (Smart Data & Self Test), Post a screenshot

Comment: @JesseHuisken May be you need to convert your hard -disk from GPT to MBR

Comment: @JesseHuisken Or might re-install Ubuntu in a GPT BIOS setting

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMMdNke-gkY&ebc=ANyPxKqi7_V_ijdGp4SyNbxMHtw_s9k6BIltE60M8y_4qsFsegbUIexOxOjAsAHon2qWYG6iqnunSyZj3SkF2__QVZM1FqL8eQ

Comment: @JesseHuisken I can not help you more than this?

Comment: try this `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) choose `Try Ubuntu` from Live CD

2.) launch [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) .

3.) click `Advanced option`

4.) go to the `GRUB options` tab

5.) tick the `out-of-disk` option

6.) click `Apply`

reboot the System.

If this did not work try from terminal `sudo apt-get install grub2` when your system boots-up and then use `Grub-customizer`to place it on `/dev/sda1`.[Install Grub Customizer in Ubuntu 14.04 to Manage Your Grub Bootloader](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/)

Comment: This proved to be ineffective.

Comment: @JesseHuisken Then try and search in AU and Google for the solution or start a bounty on you Question

Comment: @JesseHuisken I just had lost 100 reputation may be ask someone and request in  a chat room to do this for you.

Comment: @JesseHuisken By the way /dev/Sda5 is your Swap did you created yourself what are your system configuration.?

Comment: @JesseHuisken I've started bounty :)

Comment: @JesseHuisken Let us see some other Answers

Comment: Yes, anybody else have any suggestions. My separate boot partition is at the front of the drive. I also have a partition for my home directory.

Comment: @JesseHuisken ask bytecommander he might help you probably.

Comment: Okay. @bytecommander any suggestions? Just to summarize after a shutdown I can only boot into my linux install by first booting from my live USB. I receive a variety of erros, currently 'unknown filesystem'.

Comment: @JesseHuisken I feel you are stuck to this problem since last year so I will advice you after few days install Ubuntu16.04 LTS

Comment: Updating Ubuntu from Pangolin to Tahr had no effect previously.

Comment: @JesseHuisken `sudo apt-get install grub2` from terminal after your machine boots up from Live USB

Comment: @JesseHuisken After doing this install `grub-customizer' http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: @JesseHuisken and then place Grub on /dev/sda1

Comment: @JesseHuisken see my answer again this might help you....

Answer (score 1):

**What might have happened**

GRUB could have been installed on your USB stick.

**How can I (potentially) fix it?**

1. Type in  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo apt-get install grub2`

Please tell me if this didn't work, because I would like to try to help again.

Comment: I had tried this in the past without effect, and have tried it again. No result and same output from fdisk -l

Comment: @JesseHuisken Sorry for your loss.

Comment: My loss? Minor inconvenience. Thanks for trying to help regardless.

Comment: you need to mount and place Grub to the start of partition

Comment: may be you need grub-rescue

Comment: @lolreppeatlol Please type correct syntax to install grub at right place

Comment: @lolreppeatlol The person had this problem since last year though I've offered you bounty